# Reduce RAM usage in Kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I'm trying to train an ML model in Kaggle, working with a pretty large dataset. It consists of an array of pictures imported as a numpy array of size (34792, 369, 103, 4), i.e. 34792 images of 369*103 pixels using a CMYK scale. I can import the dataset and divide it into a train and test without a problem, but when I try to apply the fit method inside k-fold, the notebook crashes because it uses too much memory. I've converted everything into uint8, deleted arrays after I stop using them and use the garbage collector, non used arrays, but it's still not enough. What can I do to lower the memory usage? Here is the code I'm using:

```
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

for train, val in kfold.split(X_train):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=X_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', restore_best_weights= True, patience=5, verbose=1)
callback = [early_stop]


history = model.fit(X_train[train], y_train[train], epochs = 50, validation_data=(X_train[val], y_train[val]), batch_size=64, callbacks=callback)


scores = model.evaluate(X_train[val], y_train[val], verbose=0)
print(scores)
```

Comment: Do you need to hold the entire training and testing datasets in memory in order to train and then test?

Comment: In the script above I didn't even load the test set, only the training set, which is then divided into the training and validation sets. So, again, no test set and still crashes because of lack of memory :/